# Is this a correct proof for the following summation problem?

Tags: solution-verification, summation

There is the following problem in my math book, but the author did not include a solution.

> Let $a_i$ and $b_{ij}$ be expressions dependent on i and j. Prove that: $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \sum_{j=1}^m b_{ij} = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m a_ib_{ij}$$

I tried doing this the following way:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \sum_{j=1}^m b_{ij}=a_1\sum_{j=1}^m b_{1j}+a_2\sum_{j=1}^m b_{2j}+...+a_n\sum_{j=1}^m b_{nj}=\sum_{j=1}^m a_1b_{1j}+\sum_{j=1}^m a_2b_{2j}+...+\sum_{j=1}^m a_nb_{nj}=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m a_ib_{ij}$$

Would this be a correct proof? If not, what have I done wrong?

Comment: Yeah it seems correct. What I don't understand is that if you can "pull" $a_1$ inside the sum $a_1\sum_{j=1}^m b_{1j}$, why don't you do that directly with the original sum?

Comment: Are you asking why I did not pull $a_i$ directly into into $\sum_{j=1}^m b_{ij}$ right away?

Comment: Yes @volticus. If you do it in the second step, why not directly

Comment: Am I not using the statement I am trying to prove in the proof itself then @D S? $a_1\sum_{j=1}^m b_{1j}=\sum_{j=1}^m a_1b_{1j}$ would follow directly from $\sum_{i=1}^n ca_i = c\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ where c is a constant. But saying $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \sum_{j=1}^m b_{ij} = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m a_ib_{ij}$ would be different since $a_i$ is not a constant in this case.

Comment: Not quite. You are using the distributivity of multiplication over addition if you say "$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \sum_{j=1}^m b_{ij} = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m a_ib_{ij}$ is trivially true by distributivity of multiplication over addition"

Answer (score 0):

A potential problem of your proof: the meaning of "$\cdots$" is *intuitively* obvious but *formally* unclear.

How rigurous is your book?

How is $\sum$ defined in your book? With "$\cdots$"? Maybe using induction?

My suggestion: start proving
$$a\sum_{j=1}^m b_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^m a b_{ij}.$$

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i :=a_1+a_2+...+a_n$ in my book. I would have done the proof you asked be about like this: $\sum_{j=1}^m ab_{ji} = ab_{1i}+ab_{2i}+...+ab_{mi}=a(b_{1i}+b_{2i}+...+b_{mi})=a\sum_{j=1}^m b_{ji}$. This is also how the author did the proof (with other symbols) earlier in the chapter. Why is "..." formally unclear?

Comment: @volticus, https://math.hmc.edu/funfacts/derivative-paradox/